# Create a user profile upon registration add profile form fields to devise registrations#new form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, registration, profile, creation

I have a rails 3.1 app with devise:

- User has_one profile
- Profile belongs_to user
- Overruled the devise registration_controller
- Custom registration views all working fine, registration works fine

Now I could like to add this:

- On the registration page I want to add fields from the profile, like first name, lastname
- There is no user yet, that is going to be created when submitting the form
- I need the profile to be created with this first name,last

How would I do this? I tried several ideas, also from stack overflow but cannot seem to get it working. I tried nested attributes wich is not working the way to do this would to create a profile record in the db at the moment the user registers wich inserts the first name and last name

My registrations#new view:

```
= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f|

    = devise_error_messages!

    = f.input :username,                  :label => 'Username'
    = f.input :email,                     :label => 'Email'
    = f.input :password,                  :label => 'Password'
    = f.input :password_confirmation,     :label => 'Password confirm'

    // start fields for profile
    = f.fields_for :profile do |f|
      = f.label :bod_day
      = f.text_field :bod_day
    // end fields for profile


    = f.button :submit, t(:submit, :scope => :register)
```

In my user model i have this:

```
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is that no profile exists on that user when the form is rendered, a simple way to get round this might be to build it in memory before rendering the fields like so:

```
= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f|

    = devise_error_messages!

    = f.input :username,                  :label => 'Username'
    = f.input :email,                     :label => 'Email'
    = f.input :password,                  :label => 'Password'
    = f.input :password_confirmation,     :label => 'Password confirm'

    // make a new profile in memory
    = resource.build_profile

    // start fields for profile
    = f.fields_for :profile do |f|
      = f.label :bod_day
      = f.text_field :bod_day
    // end fields for profile


    = f.button :submit, t(:submit, :scope => :register)
```

Comment: Thanks I totally missed this as a relative ruby newbie, sometimes things seem to be less complicated then they look. thx! this fixed my issue with the below addition

Comment: it is a bit "dirty" to initialize the model in the view. I tried overriding the registration controller but there is no "hook" to override the resource initialization without duplicating code. any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Nesbitt's solution, add this to your model

```
attr_accessible ..., :profile_attributes
```

Comment: Always necessary yes, thanks for answer its now finally working correctly

Comment: Can you specify in which model should go the attr_accesible ?